# Regular Expression for matching 0 or more words with commas

Tags: .net, regex

I need to create a RegEx in .NET that will match the following:

The word AAA

... followed by zero or more of the following words: BBB CCC DDD EEE in any order. (Those words cannot repeat themselves)

... which can have commas+spaces between them, but don't have to

... followed by FFF

For example, the following should match:

```
AAA, BBB CCC, FFF
AAA CCC FFF
AAA DDD, BBB FFF
AAA FFF
```

While the following shouldn't:

```
AAA BBB BBB FFF
AAA CCC DDD
```

What should be the RegEx for this?

Thanks!

Comment: The _"Those words cannot repeat themselves"_ part is what makes this difficult.

Comment: This is a job for a parser, not a Regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could suit your needs:

```
^AAA[\s,]+(?:(BBB|CCC|DDD|EEE)(?!.*\1)[,\s]+)*FFF$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/IfTOb36yr_AFtpII)

Demo on [RegExr](http://regexr.com?37ue6)

Comment: Wow Debuggex is awesome. Good resource!

Comment: Wow, this is great! I wasn't aware of those tools. Thanks!